# How Can I convert Laravel default timestamp of created_at filed in a Controller and return through API

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get last record updated time in a proper format. Right now **updated_at** field is default laravel field. The code below return through API as json data: **updated_at: "2020-08-01T09:10:01.000000Z"**

This is not readable. I tried different conversion method, No one worked.

Code in controller:

```
public function index()  
    {

        $updatedon = Corona::all('updated_at')->last();
        
        return $updatedon;
                
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do

1. in your `Corona` model you can add

```
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

you can change the format as you wish, you can read more about [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

2. while getting the last record you can do

```
collect(Corona::all('updated_at')->last())->map(function ($updated_at) {
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeString($updated_at)->format('Y-m-d');
}))
```

or simply you can do this

```
$last_record = Corona::all('updated_at')->last();
return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeString($last_record->updated_at)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Eloquent converts the timestamps columns to instances of Carbon

```
$updateon->diffForHumans();
```

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff
This will give you human readable format like 1 day ago, etc

OR
to any custom format

```
$updateon->format('Y-m-d');
```